# Trying to minify JS file, but code not working in Linux CentOS terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm, centos7

`NODE_ENV=production browserify -t [reactify --es6] main.js | uglify-js > compiled.min.js` is not working when I run it in the Linux terminal. I've already installed NodeJS and npm. Any suggestions?

What I get in my terminal

[image]

Code I'm trying to use in terminal

[image]

Comment: _“I've already installed NodeJS and npm.”_ - and then you installed the components as well, as the first line in your second screenshot shows …?

Comment: @sandyJoshi Yes, I just doubled checked.